# angular-ui-carousel just showing next and previous buttons. No slider or images

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angular-ui-carousel as mentioned in https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-carousel. However when I code it up it just shows the previous and next buttons. Can anyone please suggest what I have done wrong. I am also open to other ways of creating multi-item carousel. Please help as I am stuck!

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.css">
     <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "/BookBox/assets/libs/angular-ui-carousel/dist/ui-carousel.css">
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.js"></script>
      <script src="/BookBox/assets/libs/angular-ui-carousel/dist/ui-carousel.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="/BookBox/components/anonymousHomePage/anonymousHomePageService.js"></script>
       <script src="/BookBox/components/anonymousHomePage/anonymousHomePageController.js"></script>
       <script src="/BookBox/shared/searchBox/searchBoxService.js"></script>
      <script src="/BookBox/shared/searchBox/searchBoxController.js"></script>
      <style>

      </style>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="anonymousHomePageCtrl" ng-controller="anonymousHomeCtrl as ctrl">

      <div style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
       <ui-carousel 
       slides="ctrl.popularBooks"
       slides-to-show="4"
       slides-to-scroll="1"
       initial-slide="1"
       autoplay="false"
       dots="false">

  <carousel-item>
    <a href="#" >
     <img alt="category1" ng-src="{{item.localImageUrl}}" height="200" width="100">
     <div class='d-flex justify-content-center'>
         <span>{{item.title}}</span>
     </div>
     <div class='d-flex justify-content-center'>
         <span>{{item.author}}</span>
     </div>
   </a>
  </carousel-item>
</ui-carousel>
</div>         
    </body>
</html>
```

Array in my angular controller:

```
self.popularBooks=[{title:"A Brief Hstory of Time", author:"Stephen Hawking", localImageUrl:"http://localhost:8383/BookBox/assets/img/bookCovers/I1.jpg"},
                         {title:"Life In Motion", author:"Misty Copeland", localImageUrl:"http://localhost:8383/BookBox/assets/img/bookCovers/I2.jpg"},
                         {title:"Loosing My Virginity", author:"Richard Branson", localImageUrl:"http://localhost:8383/BookBox/assets/img/bookCovers/I3.jpg"},
                         {title:"Wings Of Fire", author:"APJ Abdul Kalam", localImageUrl:"http://localhost:8383/BookBox/assets/img/bookCovers/I4.jpg"},
                         {title:"Thinking Fast and Slow", author:"Daniel Kahnamen", localImageUrl:"http://localhost:8383/BookBox/assets/img/bookCovers/I5.jpg"}];
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this issue?